# how to load html5 code in a ionic page

Tags: javascript, css, html, ionic-framework

Hello I have a App i'm working on in ionic  and I am trying to load a mobile calculator that I did in html in the ionic page but when I load my app it looks like it's not loading the css or js code so how do I get to do that?

here's my code:

```
<ion-view title="Math">
  <ion-content padding="true" class="has-header">


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-touch-fullscreen" content="yes">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- powerTouch -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/powertouch-js-1.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/core.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/base.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/moz.css">
    <!-- font -->
    <link href="css/font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/l10n.js"></script>
    <link rel="resource" type="application/l10n" href="locales.ini">


    <script>
      $(function(){
                var powerTouch = $.powerTouch();
                powerTouch.attachTouch(".ui-el");
                powerTouch.attachGesture(".ui-gesture", {"acceleration":0});
            });
    </script>


    <div class="frame">
      <div class="film">
        <div class="calc">
          <div class="result ui-gesture">
            <div class="cwrap fontlight hide">
              <a href="javascript:;" data-longtap="1" class="cancel ui-el">×</a>
            </div>
            <div class="exp fontlight" id="exp">
              <div class="string" id="string">
                <div id="string-film">
                  <!--<div class="text-frame">
                                        <span id="text"></span>
                                    </div>-->
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="keys">

            <table class="pulsanti">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert ui-el par" data-val="(" data-long=")" data-longtap="1">
                      <span class="label rel">(
                        <span class="apice apM tohide">)</span>
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn action ui-el third" data-action="M" data-longtap="1" id="btn-m">
                      <span class="label rel">M
                        <span class="apice apM">×</span>
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn action ui-el third" data-action="Mr">
                      <span class="label rel">Mr</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert ui-el oper" data-val="+">
                      <span class="label">+</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert generic ui-el" data-val="7">
                      <span class="label">7</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert generic ui-el" data-val="8">
                      <span class="label">8</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert generic ui-el" data-val="9">
                      <span class="label">9</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert ui-el oper" data-val="-">
                      <span class="label">—</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert generic ui-el" data-val="4">
                      <span class="label">4</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert generic ui-el" data-val="5">
                      <span class="label">5</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert generic ui-el" data-val="6">
                      <span class="label">6</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert ui-el oper" data-val="*">
                      <span class="label">×</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert generic ui-el" data-val="1">
                      <span class="label">1</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert generic ui-el" data-val="2">
                      <span class="label">2</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert generic ui-el" data-val="3">
                      <span class="label">3</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert ui-el oper" data-val=":">
                      <span class="label">÷</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert generic ui-el" data-val="0">
                      <span class="label">0</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert generic ui-el" data-val=".">
                      <span class="label">,</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td colspan="2">
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert ui-el uguale">
                      <span class="label">=</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>

                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>

            <table class="pulsanti extra">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <a id="close-tonda" href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert ui-el par" data-val=")">
                      <span class="label">)</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert ui-el par" data-val="[" data-long="]" data-longtap="1">
                      <span class="label rel">[
                        <span class="apice apM">]</span>
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert ui-el par toshow" data-val="{" data-long="}" data-longtap="1">
                      <span class="label rel">{
                        <span class="apice apM">}</span>
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert ui-el second" data-val="%">
                      <span class="label">%</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert  mini ui-el second" data-val="sin(" data-alert="1">
                      <span class="label">sin</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert  mini ui-el second" data-val="cos(" data-alert="1">
                      <span class="label">cos</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert  mini ui-el second" data-val="tan(" data-alert="1">
                      <span class="label">tan</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert  ui-el oper" data-val="e">
                      <span class="label">e</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert  mini ui-el second" data-val="asin(" data-alert="1">
                      <span class="label">asin</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert  mini ui-el second" data-val="acos(" data-alert="1">
                      <span class="label">acos</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert  mini ui-el second" data-val="atan(" data-alert="1">
                      <span class="label">atan</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert ui-el oper" data-val="π">
                      <span class="label">π</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert  ui-el second" data-val="^2">
                      <span class="label rel">x
                        <span class="apice">2</span>
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert ui-el second" data-val="^">
                      <span class="label rel">y
                        <span class="apice">x</span>
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </td>


                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert mini second ui-el" data-val="log(" data-alert="1">
                      <span class="label">log</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>

                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert ui-el second" data-val="!">
                      <span class="label">x!</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>

                </tr>
                <tr>

                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert second ui-el" data-val="sqrt(" data-alert="1">
                      <span class="label">√</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <a href="javascript:;" class="buttn insert ui-el second" data-val="root(" data-alert="1">
                      <span class="label rel">
                        <span class="apice rad">x</span>√</span>
                    </a>
                  </td>

                  <td colspan="2">

                    <button id="math-button1" ion-button="" class="buttn insert mini second ui-el" block="" href-inappbrowser="page7">
                      Tools
                    </button>

                  </td>

                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="info-page scrollable">
          <div class="page-content page">
            <div class="section border">
              <a href="javascript:;" class="ui-el backbutton left">&lt;</a>
              <div class="clear"></div>
              <h2 class="left">calculator</h2>
              <div class="clear"></div>
              <p class="subtitle" data-l10n-id="SubTitleApp">
                Simple and powerful scientific calculator
              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="section border">
              <div class="speg">
                <div class="row page-header">
                  <span data-l10n-id="TitleMemory">Memory</span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">M
                  <span class="ugul">=</span>
                  <span data-l10n-id="M-symbol">write into memory</span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">Mr
                  <span class="ugul">=</span>
                  <span data-l10n-id="Mr-symbol">read from memory</span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">M
                  <span class="apice_">×</span>
                  <span class="ugul">=</span>
                  <span data-l10n-id="M-symbol-cross">Tap&amp;Hold, clear memory</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section border">
              <div class="speg">
                <div class="row page-header">
                  <span data-l10n-id="TitleHistory">History</span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">↑ ↓
                  <span class="ugul">=</span>
                  <span data-l10n-id="History-swipe">swipe up/down on calc bar</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section border">
              <div class="speg">
                <div class="row page-header">
                  <span data-l10n-id="TitleMath">Math</span>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <span class="apice_">2</span>√
                  <span class="ugul">=</span> sqrt()</div>
                <div class="row">
                  <span class="apice_">x</span>√
                  <span class="ugul">=</span>
                  <span class="pedice">x</span>root()</div>
                <div class="row">x
                  <span class="apice_">y</span>
                  <span class="ugul">=</span> x^y</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section border">
              <div class="speg">
                <div class="row page-header">
                  <span data-l10n-id="TitleSymbols">Symbols</span>
                </div>
                <div class="row text">
                  ) ] } =
                  <span data-l10n-id="TapAndHold">Tap&amp;Hold</span> ( [ {
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section ">
              <div class="speg">
                <div class="row text" data-l10n-id="DeleteAll">
                  Delete all = Tap&amp;Hold delete button
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Thank's in advance!!! :)